# Rename X11 input devices with hotplugging?

Tags: xorg, input-device

Is it possible to change the X11 input device identifiers, as they are for example listed by `xinput`? Preferably without switching to a static `xorg.conf` configuration, I'm using xorg-server 1.12.4 (archlinux).

I need to do that since, as it seems Blender identifies the Pen and Eraser of a graphics tablet using the hardcoded names "stylus" and "eraser" but by default the names of my tablet are prefixed with the type e.g. "Wacom Bamboo 16FG 4x5 Pen stylus".

**Edit:** Actually I found out this is no more the case, Blender 2.63 does correctly identify Pen and Eraser out of the box, e.g. they produce an inverse effect when sculpting. Nevertheless I would be interested in an answer just out of curiosity.